# Putting the Facebox "close button" on top right as opposed to bottom right

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I would like to position the "close" button on the top right as opposed to bottom right.

I am sure this is something you folks have done before, and I do not think it is right to reinvent the wheel =)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the HTML template in facebox.js to this:

```
  faceboxHtml  : '\
<div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
  <div class="popup"> \
    <table> \
      <tbody> \
        <tr> \
          <td class="tl"/><td class="b"/><td class="tr"/> \
        </tr> \
        <tr> \
          <td class="b"/> \
          <td class="body"> \
            <div class="footer"> \
              <a href="#" class="close"> \
                <img src="/facebox/closelabel.gif" title="close" class="close_image" /> \
              </a> \
            </div> \
            <div class="content"> \
            </div> \
          </td> \
          <td class="b"/> \
        </tr> \
        <tr> \
          <td class="bl"/><td class="b"/><td class="br"/> \
        </tr> \
      </tbody> \
    </table> \
  </div> \
</div>'
```